# How can I setup multiple/restricted users on S6 lite?

Tags: samsung, tablet, accounts

I have an S6 lite that I would like to share with the kids.

So, I would like to have a normal account that I can use, and another account that the kids can use with some supervision.

I would like to restrict the apps available on this account, which I am able to currently do.

I would also like to restrict the usage time of the tablet; the option in the tablet takes me to Family Link, which it seems I cannot install in the desired way.

From what I have understood, if I go for Family Link, it should be added in the only account in the tablet.

I have a google account configured as a child account in Family Link, but I am not able to add this account to the tablet along with my parent account.

Is there a way I can configure the S6 lite like this?

- Main Profile - No restrictions
- Kid Profile - Restrictions on available apps and time allowed

Are there any other tablets that would have allowed me to do what I wanted?

Comment: Please note that device recommendation is off-topic here. You might be interested in our sister site, [HardwareRecs.SE], but please follow [their guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205) to get a suitable device for your needs.